# How to get Mavericks Calendar to sync with Microsoft Exchange

Tags: calendar, macos, exchange, microsoft

My company uses Microsoft Exchange server for email and calendar items. How can I get that onto Calendar in the new Mavericks OS?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open **System Preferences** → **Internet Accounts**.

   [image]
2. Select Exchange from the list.

   [image]
3. Enter your account information and follow the instructions.

   [image]
4. Make sure that the Calendars option is selected.

   [image]